# Plot multiple solutions of the differential equation in a with values of constant c=-2,-1,0,1,2 in a single graph

Tags: plotting

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ans = DSolve[y'[x] == (4 y[x])/x, y[x], x]
```

> {{y[x] -> x^4 C[1]}}

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
y[x] = x^4 c
Plot[Evaluate[Table[ans, { c, -2, 2}]], {x, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: The problem is that [`ClearAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html) clears all definitions, including your `ans`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Y = DSolveValue[y'[x] == (4 y[x])/x, y , x,GeneratedParameters -> k]
Plot[Table[Evaluate[Y[x]], {k[1], -2, 2}], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]